# VSCode how to set the timezone for .NET Core Development

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have an `ASP.NET Core 3.1` environment where the server timezone is set to `UCT` and the browser is set to `local time`, e.g. Pacific.

Using the command below on `MacOS` works perfectly allowing me mimic the environment for debugging purposes.

> TZ=UCT dotnet run

How can I achieve the same using `VSCode` `launch.json` settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `launch.json` file set the environment variable `TZ` to the desired timezone.

The timezone value can be set to any zone information typically found under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` e.g. "UCT" or "Europe/Amsterdam"

```
    "name": ".NET Core Launch",
    "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development,
        "TZ": "UCT"
    },
```